# TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled

Tags: android, textview, androidx

После прокрутки `RecyclerView` текст в его item-ах можно выделить только один раз до прокрутки - после выделения текста и прокрутки `RecyclerView` текст больше не выделяется и Logcat показывает такое сообщение:

> TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled.

Эта проблема решается только [с помощью следующего "workaround-a"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40140869/4898850):

```
selectableTextView.setEnabled(false);
selectableTextView.setEnabled(true);
```

Этот баг также уже давно был опубликована на баг-трэкере:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37095917

Может, кто-нибудь может объяснить точную причину этой проблемы и знает какой-нибудь более правильный способ её решения?

Comment: Иногда помогает ширину wrap_content указывать у TextView

Comment: @McDaggen, а каким образом атрибут wrap_content влияет на выделение текста? :)

Comment: ну и вообще я посмотрела, у тех TextView item-ов RecyclerView как раз ширина wrap_content была указана, но не помогло(